# use Ajax to call function while using another ajax with preventDefault to submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, clean-urls

I am making two AJAX calls in the form. The first is to change the second select based on the first select which calling a PHP page to process the data. The second is to prevent the default post and post the data in another PHP page.

Both Functions are working if I delete the other one. I also have another problem which is the redirect to a new page (using CleanURL). Where should I redirect in the posting page, or once return to the form page?

```js
$('#brand').change(function() {
  var brandID2 = $(this).val();
  $.ajax({
    url: "Calling the models after selecting the brand",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      brandID: brandID2
    },
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
      $('#model').html(data);
    }
  });
});

$("#testform").on('submit', (function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: "Calling the post page",
    type: "POST",
    data: new FormData(this),
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data) {
      //window.location.href = "<?php echo $_SESSION['toRedirectToAfterFilters']; ?>";
    }
  });
}));
```

```html
<form name="testform" action="" method="POST">
  <select name="brand" id="brand">
    <option value=''>Select a Brand</option>
    //function to load all the brands
  </select>
  <select name="model" id="model">
    <option value="">Please Select Brand First</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit" name="submit" class="">FILTER</button>
</form>
```

Comment: "Both Functions are working if i delete the other one." What do you mean by the "Other one"

Comment: i mean if i delete the first one the second one works, and if i delete the second one the first one works

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the id on `testform`

`<form id="testform">...`

I would remove the CleanURL dependency and try out each AJAX request one at a time. Then you will immediately see the point of failure. If not, throw a `debugger;` inside each event handler and step through.

Personally, I would redirect from the server after a successful database write, to simplify the logic and not have to store the success callback URL inside the `$_SESSION` array.

Comment: i have tried to add the id="testform" but still it is not working. the functions are working fine if i use only one of them, but both together are not working. 
i think the problem in conflict or in the prevent default.

for the clean URL, i am still learning and am sending the request to the index.php using htaccess, so the best thing is to redirect from the page that post the information.
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]` in htaccess